# On calling messaging().getToken() returns object

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

I'm using @react-native-firebase/messaging version 11.5.0.

and when i request messaging().getToken() from saga, it throws below response Object:

```
{"_A": null, "_x": 0, "_y": 0, "_z": null}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this object because this is an `async` opeartion and what you are getting is kind of an incomplete result. Here is a better way to do this

```js
export const getDeviceToken = async () => {
  const token = await messaging().getToken()
  console.log(token)
  return token
}
```

Now, if you directly call this method in some other file like this
`const token = getDeviceToken();` then you will get a similar object which you have mentioned in the question. Instead, you have to do async there also, either `await` or `.then()`

```js
getDeviceToken().then((token) => console.log(token));
```

By this you will get the correct token string.